# How to connect facebook webhook to a group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I did a facebook app with a webhook. I can get it to send a test to my endpoint app, but how do I connect it to at user or a group to get real data?

I can't find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: When you subscribed for updates to user fields, then you will automatically get updates for all users of your app (that granted the relevant permissions to access the data in the first place.) For normal groups you won’t get anything though of course, because for those webhooks simply aren’t available (yet.)

Comment: Sorry no! the title is changed.

Comment: @CBroe: If I can't get a hook to the group, what would the best way to grab the updates be the? A call to the API every 5 minutes?

Comment: Depends, on what data you need and what for. Making too frequent requests could easily make you run into the Rate Limits.

Comment: But making a call every fx 5 min would be the only way to do that?

Comment: @CBroe - Do you mean subscribing to the user/feed endpoint in webhooks? I thought that only works for a user's profile, not what they comment within a group.